# Convert earth-centric coordinate frame to coordinate frame aligned to tangential plane?

Tags: math, gps, computational-geometry

Given that earth is perfectly spherical with **radius R.**
The earth-centric coordinate system **E** is defined as follows:

- The center of this sphere is the origin,
- Earth's north pole represents the **z-axis**.
- Latitude 0 and longitude 0 represent **x-axis**.
- Latitude 0 and longitude 90 represent **y- axis**.

Now at any given latitude, longitude, and altitude, we can make a local coordinate system **S** whose y-z plane is tangential to earth's surface and z points to the north pole and x points perpendicular to this plane.

I need a **4x4 transformation matrix** to transform a 3d point from earth-centric coordinate system **E** to this local coordinate system **S**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: How about I need a program to compute this transformation matrix, such transformation matrices are quite common in OpenGL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transformation matrix from S to E might be composed as product of matrices:

```
 Shift along X axis by R+Altitude
 Rotation about Y-axis by Latitude
 Rotation about Z-axis by Longitude
```

Make inverse of this matrix to get E-S transform

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that earth is spherical, this is actually not that hard.

Spherical coordinates to the rescue (see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html))! A sphere can be parametrized by 2 angles (as already mentions in the problem statement). Based on this, you can formulate equations to convert to cartesian coordinates. If you compute the derivative of those equations with respect to both angles, you get equations stating the tangent and bitangent of any point on the sphere. Based on this you can either use the vector pointing from the center to a point on the sphere as the normal or the cross product between tangent and bitangent. Formulations for tangent and bitangents are also given in the link above.

Now you got an orthogonal system for each point on the sphere based on your 3 vectors: tangent, bitangent and normal. The only part that is missing is the translation which is simply the vector pointing from the center to a point on the sphere. Given all the necessary ingredients, you can create a 4x4 matrix from those axes using standard libraries like glm or simply place those vectors as columns of your matrix (don't forget to normalize tangent, bitangent and normal!). Depending if you use row-major or column-major matrices you may need to transpose this matrix.